# initialize sessionContext and context

Tags: jboss, seam, sessioncontext

Can anyone please suggest to me how to initialize `org.jboss.seam.contexts` Context as well as session context inside IR?

I need to do it for my testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first create an application context and set the property.

```
Context appContext = new ApplicationContext();
// Set a value
appContext.set("flagvalue", new Object());
// Get a value
Contexts.getSessionContext().get("flagvalue");
```